# OData API versioning issue .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, odata, aspnet-api-versioning

I received an application startup exception, related to the OData API versioning.
The exception message:

> The entity model (EDM) does not have the required ApiVersionAnnotation annotation

The snippet of mapping versioned odata route

```
 public static IEndpointRouteBuilder MapPaymentsODataRoute(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.MapVersionedODataRoute(
            "payments-odata",
            "api/v{apiVersion:apiVersion}/payment-service/odata",
            new List<IEdmModel> { BuildEdmModel() });
    
        return builder;
    }
```

All needed API versioning services registered in DI container.

See endpoint configuration:
[endpoint configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39U3G.png)

See controller example:
[controller example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU08i.png)

Any thoughts? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what `BuildEdmModel()` does, but it would appear that you are building it manually instead of via the **VersionedODataModelBuilder**. This is *allowed*, but know that you need to set the **ApiVersionAnnotation**. API Versioning for OData uses an *EDM per API Version* approach, which keeps everything clearly segregated. API Versioning determines how to match up the EDM by comparing the applied **ApiVersionAnnotation** with the resolved, incoming API Version. *"There can be only one."*

If you're building the EDMs yourself, you need to add this required annotation to the model itself:

```cs
edm.SetAnnotationValue(edm, new ApiVersionAnnotation(new ApiVersion(1, 0)));
```

If you only have a single version, this is pretty easy to build. If you have several versions, it gets more complex. The **VersionedODataModelBuilder** achieves this by creating a unioned set of all API versions, from all OData APIs, discovered through **IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider**. For every discovered OData API version, a set of **IModelConfiguration** instances are used to *apply* the configuration for that particular EDM in a particular API Version, including nothing at all (e.g. excluded). This is determined by the implementer (e.g. developer). Depending on the complexity of your application, you might use a single **IModelConfiguration**, one per entity, or none at all and just use the `VersionedODataModelBuilder.DefaultModelConfiguration` callback.

Regardless of the approach you use, if the **ApiVersionAnnotation** is set, you'll be back in business.

---

UPDATE: In response to the added images.

There are several additional points:

- If you *inject* **VersionedODataModelBuilder** from DI or explicitly resolve it from **IServiceProvider**, all of the work is done for you.
- If you just pass the **VersionedODataModelBuilder** to `MapVersionedODataRoute` as a parameter, it will do the *right* thing. Due to OData's *prefix* concept, the **IModelConfiguration** can vary by API version **and** path. Alternatively, you can call `VersionedODataModelBuilder.GetEdmModels('path')`. If there are no differences between the prefixes, then you're fine.
- The main issue appears to be that your controller name doesn't match up. API Versioning collates API by controller name because - well - it's the only consistent and reliable thing that can be used. This is important for matching up the corresponding EDM as well. It's not clear what **PaymentsODataRouteAttribute** actually does; however, if it sets the `controller` route parameter, then it *should* work. If not, then your controller name needs to match or you can use the provided `[ControllerName("payments")]` to satisfy the requirement. I assume the name of the corresponding entity set is `Payments`.
- No idea what **EnableODataAttribute** is. That doesn't appear to be a standard attribute. Inheriting from **ODataController** will enable the OData features.
- OData does **not** support the API Explorer out-of-the-box. If you're not also using the API Versioning API Explorer extensions for OData, configuring `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]` will likely cause errors at runtime. The API Versioning extensions are *aware* that **ODataController** explicitly opts out of the API Explorer. By default, it will completely ignore the `IgnoreApi` setting so that you don't have to reconfigure and opt in every single **ODataController**. If you really want to use **ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute**, then you can configure the API Explorer extensions to honor it with `ODataApiExplorerOptions.UseApiExplorerSettings`, which defaults to `false`. If you don't change it to `true`, the setting is completely ignored which may include controllers that you intentionally marked as `IgnoreApi = true`.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Application startup exception disappeared. But the controller's action returns 404 Not Found. Controllers defined and actions too.

Comment: That may just be a routing misconfiguration. Can you share more? It's hard to answer with so little information. The next _interesting_ thing would probably be a skeleton of your controller with the actions, route info, etc.

Comment: See endpoint configuration: https://prnt.sc/1tytpq9
See controller example: https://prnt.sc/1tyui6l

Can I map versioned odata routes more than once?

Comment: Unfortunately, those links didn't show anything. It looks like they point to some type of app to install. :S If you're not able to update your question, perhaps something like a Gist post or something? API Versioning makes every effort to not change anything about routing. The goal is to merely disambiguate routes by an API version discriminator, which is not intrinsically possible out-of-the-box. In short, yes - it is possible to map multiple routes and/or versions to a single action.

Comment: Question updated with images.

Comment: Updated answer to the provided images.

Comment: Thanks, for your support.
I did all, as you mentioned. But now when I call OData action, I always received that API version not supported. Chris do you have any messenger, where I can share more information directly?

Comment: or maybe an email?

Comment: If you're able to post a repro, that will be helpful. If you can't here, then you always can at the [API Versioning](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues). **Disclaimer**: I am the owner. I also recommend reviewing the [Basic OData](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/ODataBasicSample) and [OpenAPI OData](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerODataSample). OData has a lot of quirks. There's always a chance of a bug.